# How can I show array in table?

Tags: php, html

I have an array. And I want to show in table format like

Date would be on column and advertiser's name would be on row.

EXAMPLE:

```
DATE         | abc | def | xyz
2016-10-26   | 0   | 0   | 0
2016-10-27   | 0   | 0   | 0
```

Data sample:

```
Array ( [2016-10-26] => Array ( [abc] => 0 [def] => 0 [xyz] => 0  ) 
[2016-10-27] => Array ( [abc] => 0 [def] => 0 [xyz] => 0 )
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Comment: well - iterate over your array and write a table row for each dataset?

Comment: I tried nothing. I don't get any idea to implement this. @ObjectManipulator

Comment: There are about 5482845382857 examples of creating html tables from data stored in an array alone here on SO. None of those helped? _Why not_? What is different in your situation, so that none of the examples help?

Comment: So this is a ___Do it for me___ question then! We here attempt to fix your code, we dont attempt to write your code

Comment: Apart from all those examples there are endless beginners tutorials for php programming. They all show how to implement tables.

Comment: @JayDoshi : Try it first. If Stuck, Feel Free To Ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tutorials based on Array, which you need to go through it for basic understanding.

***Quick Start***

- [Arrays - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [Arrays - Tutorial Points](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm)
- [Multidimensional Arrays - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp)

***Code***

```
<?php
$arr["2016-10-26"] = ['abc'=> 0, 'def'=> 0, 'xyz'=> 0];
$arr["2016-10-27"] = ['abc'=> 0, 'def'=> 0, 'xyz'=> 0];

print_r($arr);
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>abc</th>
    <th>def</th>
    <th>xyz</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($arr as $key=>$val){?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$key;?></td>
    <td><?=$val['abc']?></td>
    <td><?=$val['def']?></td>
    <td><?=$val['xyz']?></td>
  <?php }?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***Output***

> Array ( [2016-10-26] => Array ( [abc] => 0 [def] => 0 [xyz] => 0 )
>   [2016-10-27] => Array ( [abc] => 0 [def] => 0 [xyz] => 0 ) )

```
Date       abc  def xyz
2016-10-26  0   0   0
2016-10-27  0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with foreach() function for array to get the result. Below code may help you.

```
<?php
$rows =  array ('2016-10-26' => array ( 'abc' => 0, 'def' => 0, 'xyz' => 0  ) ,
              '2016-10-27' => array ( 'abc' => 0, 'def' => 0, 'xyz' => 0 ));

?>
<table >
<thead>
<th>DATE</th>
<th>abc</th>
<th>def</th>
<th>def</th>
</thead>
<?php  foreach($rows as $key=>$val) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $val['abc']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $val['def'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $val['xyz'] ?></td>
    </tr>   
  <?php } ?>
 </table>
```